# swift case falling through

Tags: switch-statement, swift

Does swift have fall through statement? e.g if I do the following

```
var testVar = "hello"
var result = 0

switch(testVal)
{
case "one":
    result = 1
case "two":
    result = 1
default:
    result = 3
}
```

is it possible to have  the same code executed for case "one" and case "two"?

Answer (score 389, accepted):

Yes. You can do so as follows:

```
var testVal = "hello"
var result = 0

switch testVal {
case "one", "two":
    result = 1
default:
    result = 3
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the `fallthrough` keyword:

```
var testVal = "hello"
var result = 0

switch testVal {
case "one":
    fallthrough
case "two":
    result = 1
default:
    result = 3
}
```

Comment: +1 for not just mentioning `fallthrough`, but suggesting to use multi-case

Comment: This is such a good compromise between the danger of C's fall through, and the lack of fall through in for example, C#

Comment: Does anyone know how to fall through from a case to default?  case "two", default: won't compile.

Comment: Never mind.  I realized that commenting out the case makes it part of the default cases set, so: /*case "two",*/ default: has the effect I'm looking for.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov C# has explicit fall through

Comment: @IanNewson Oh i'm mistaken, I probably confused it for some other lang

Comment: FWIW it's not good practice to only have a fallthrough in an otherwise empty case.

Answer (score 8):

```
var testVar = "hello"

switch(testVar) {

case "hello":

    println("hello match number 1")

    fallthrough

case "two":

    println("two in not hello however the above fallthrough automatically always picks the     case following whether there is a match or not! To me this is wrong")

default:

    println("Default")
}
```

Comment: Do you know of a way to fall through to the default case?

Comment: i agree with "case two". For me this behavior sucks. Why does Swift execute the next case even it's not true? This makes the switch statement totally useless...

Answer (score 8):

Here is example for you easy to understand:

```
let value = 0

switch value
{
case 0:
    print(0) // print 0
    fallthrough
case 1:
    print(1) // print 1
case 2:
    print(2) // Doesn't print
default:
    print("default")
}
```

Conclusion: Use `fallthrough` to execute next case (only one) when the previous one that have `fallthrough` is match or not.

Answer (score 7):

```
case "one", "two":
    result = 1
```

There are no break statements, but cases are a lot more flexible.

**Addendum:** As Analog File points out, there actually are `break` statements in Swift.  They're still available for use in loops, though unnecessary in `switch` statements, unless you need to fill an otherwise empty case, as empty cases are not allowed.  For example: `default: break`.

Answer (score 2):

The keyword `fallthrough` at the end of a case causes the fall-through behavior you're looking for, and multiple values can be checked in a single case.